# codeigniter: why is that when i echo base_url() in an href attribute of an anchor tag, it echoes twice

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, anchor, base-url

so basically when i echo the codeigniter function base_url() in the href attribute of an anchor tag, it appears to echo it out twice.  Example:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">somelink</a>
```

and the above, if you inspect it your chrome browser shows this:

```
<a href="www.mysitedomainname.com/www.mysitedomainname.com/">somelink</a>
```

"mysitedomainname.com" is just a name i made up for this example.  Any reason why this is happening?

Comment: How do you define your base_url setting in your config file?

Comment: $config['base_url']= 'www.mysitedomainname.com/';

Comment: @dave Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three reasons I'm aware about that can cause this.

The first one is when something wrong is written in `config.php` on line 17 `$config['base_url']    = '';` - it better be left empty, just like when you download CI.

The second one is if you have set `$config['base_url']` value to something without prefixing it with `http://` or other protocol.

The third one is if you have set `base` `href` somewhere:

```
<base href="http://www.mysitedomainname.com/" />
```

When you need to link to some other page, you *should* use `site_url()`, `base_url()` can be used to link stylesheets, js, img src attributes and other *real* URL's. The reason is pretty simple, `base_url()` does not include the `index_page` value set in `config.php`.

Comment: wow the second one was the issue...man i spent hours, literally killing myself trying to figure this out...why in the hell would http:// make a difference?

Comment: Because that's basic HTML functionality, try to write down in plain HTML `<a href="something">1</a>` - it will prepend the current URL. And it's better to not set this value to anything at all, CodeIgniter will handle this for you and you will not have to change it when you deploy your project.

Comment: @SergeyTelshevsky - what will happen if I kept it empty `$config['base_url'] = ""`

Comment: @VilasGalave I don't know. It's 2016, don't use codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

It will work fine if you use

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('Controller/Function'); ?>">somelink</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

make this

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://www.mysitedomainname.com"
```

into this

```
$config['base_url'] = ""
```

in config.php