# Codeigniter base_url() in whack?

Tags: codeigniter, base-url

I was trying to set up a basic log in form with a following code:

```
<?=form_open(base_url() . 'main/login'); ?>
```

However after submitting the form the url shows this:

```
example.com/main/http//example.com/http//example.com/main/login
```

So I guess in essence for some reason the base-url is printed twice before the controller/method declaration.  If I clear the base url value in my config file then the application works normally.  I am however curious on what could cause this.  For additional information I am working on xampp with a virtualhost and I have mod-rewrite on with a .htaccess file located at the document root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter automatically adds the base_url to the action of the form when you use the form helper.

For example, you can use:

```
<?=form_open('main/login'); ?>
```

which will produce:
http//example.com/main/login

And a correct URL! Pretty simple! :D
More information at:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 1):

The file `config.php` under **application/config** has the setting:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

Give it the folder/directory path. For example:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci_test/';
```

Don't forget to mention the protocol (http://). Alternatively try the `site_url()` method instead of `base_url()` for form opening. Skip it if using the `form_open()` function:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('main/login'); ?>"> ... </form>
```

Or

```
<?php form_open('main/login'); ?>
```

For more help: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Not sure about the `.htaccess` file you have used. But this might be the answer [codeigniter: why is that when i echo base_url() in an href attribute of an anchor tag, it echoes twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444121/codeigniter-why-is-that-when-i-echo-base-url-in-an-href-attribute-of-an-ancho)

Answer (score 0):

Try it by parameter:

```
<?=form_open(base_url('main/login')); ?>
```

or

```
<?=form_open site_url('main/login')); ?>
```

In order to append the prefix also

Answer (score 0):

You can Use

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url(main/login)); ?>
```

You have to use "echo" rather than  because it not works in some browsers....